# Displaying a picture from a URL into wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

Can anyone tell me how I can download a picture from a URL and display it on one my wxPython?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [wx.Image](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html) and load the image data using a method like [LoadStream](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#LoadStream) or [LoadMimeStream](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#LoadMimeStream) from an input stream or a file-like object.

To fetch the image data itself, use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/).